# Flutter / Dart syntax Inside an anonymous function

Tags: flutter, dart

Given the following block of code in Flutter, I am seeing syntax errors that I wouldn't expect

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () => {
        //undefined name x, Expected to find ','
        int x = 12; 

        //Unexpected text 'return'
        if (_timer != null && _timer!.isActive)
        {
          return
        }

        _timer =
            Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 250), (timer) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            myKeys[i].currentState?.roll();
          }
        })
      },
  child: const Icon(Icons.check),
),
```

In JS (or c#) something like this works fine:

```
const f = ()=> {
  var j = "123";
  console.log(j);
  return;
}
```

Other than "because it wasn't implemented that way", why doesn't this work in Dart and what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Ok you need `() { ...`, not `() => { ...`

Comment: In Dart, `() => { ... }` declares a zero-argument anonymous function that returns a `Set` literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your onTap-parameter:
either you use a block body `() {}` for more than one statement or an arrow-function for a single statement `() => print("hello world")`

Also don't forget the semicolon after the `return` keyword

fixed solution:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    int x = 12;

    if (_timer != null && _timer!.isActive) {
      return;
    }

    _timer =
        Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 250), (timer) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        myKeys[i].currentState?.roll();
      }
    });
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.check),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

> Both Dart and JavaScript support arrow syntax (=>), but they are
> different. In Dart, arrow syntax is only used when the function
> contains a single expression or return statement.

[dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/coming-from/js-to-dart)

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are used for single statement execution such as,

`onPressed: () => Navigator.push(//stuff in here);`

whereas block statements are used for multiple statements to execute i.e.

```
onPressed: (){
// Do a lot of stuff in here
},
```